# Typescript Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

I have component that accept Item, ant I use interface to describe it, but inside component
I use next construction (I use another property to get currentItem field)

```
modalComponentsData.reduce((acc: any, el: any) => {
         acc[el.name] = currentItem[el.name]
         return acc
       }, {}),
```

And I get next warning

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; id?: string | undefined; }'

interface IItem{
  name: string,
  id: string
}

export default function ModalGroupComponent({currentItem}: IItem{

....some logic

modalComponentsData.reduce((acc: any, el: any) => {
         acc[el.name] = currentItem[el.name]
         return acc
       }, {}),
}
```

Comment: Try giving `acc` and `el` better types.

Comment: Where is `currentItem` being declared? `(acc: IItem[], el: IItem)` might work for the arrow function but have you tried it without the type declaration?

Comment: It ditnt help unfornunatlly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
interface IItem {
    name: string;
    id: string;
}

interface IItemDict {
    [key: string]: IItem
}

interface IComponent {
    currentItem: IItemDict;
}

interface IElement {
    name: string;
}

export default function ModalGroupComponent({currentItem}: IComponent) {

    // ....some logic

    modalComponentsData.reduce((acc: IItemDict, el: IElement) => {
        acc[el.name] = currentItem[el.name]
        return acc
    }, {});
}
```